# How to insert/update document from existing docusign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I created an envelope via Docusign Web Service in my application now i get an requirement that we have to insert/update or change document from existing envelope.

I have read few articles which stated that we can change document with in template or basically from draft envelope.

Is there any way/functionality through which we can update document from existing/already send or in-process envelope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DocuSign REST API:

- Documents can only be removed from a DRAFT ENVELOPE. Once an envelope has been Sent, Documents cannot be removed.
- Documents can only be added to a DRAFT ENVELOPE. Once an envelope has been Sent, Documents cannot be added.

I believe, however, that it ***IS*** possible to add/remove documents from an "in-process" Envelope (i.e., an Envelope that's already been sent) by using the DocuSign SOAP API.